# How do I align columns to a grid and center the last row?

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I achieve the following layout:

[image]

I've attempted to use flexbox, justifying the content using `jusitfy-content: space-around;`. Which almost works, except the first row each column is justified to the container.

Additionally, this may have to work with six items. In that instance then the bottom row should reflect the same as the top row.

Items are generated dynamically.

Is this at all possible? How would I achieve this?

Comment: For a proper answer a minimal working code snippet is needed.

Comment: I've done something similar before, but from memory I used bootstrap. I'll try look for the project. Are the items generated dynamically? Edit - Also code snippets would help a tonne

Comment: Hi, yes they are generated dynamically. Apologies @LGSon I'm on my home computer. The code snippet I was working on is on my work computer.

Comment: Do you need the first and right containers to be sticking to the left and right borders of the browser?

Comment: So you don't need to head back to the office and your question doesn't get closed ;-) https://jsfiddle.net/vx58mrpp/

Comment: i think you question could be interesting if you give us more detail of what you expect

Answer (score -1):

I added a button which you can use to generate more boxes with the `class "thing"` in the flexbox and see how the layout changes. Hope, it helps. :)

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".things").append("<div class='thing'></div>");
});
```

```css
.things {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.thing {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:30px;
  flex:1 0 300px;
  min-width:300px;
  max-width:350px;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>CLick me to make boxes!</button>

<div class="things">
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, this is what they are asking for. "How do I achieve the following layout:" without the question mark that is ;)

Comment: ah yes, i miss understand the question as he was talking about the last row .. anyway it's not clear :)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked if they meant what I just posted since it provides the layout that they require.

Comment: Did you downvoted mine as you thought I downvoted yours?

Comment: Great...just wanted to ask

Comment: @LGSon For that matter why is this one downvoted? Did you downvote mine though? lol

Comment: Nope...and some just do w/o comments

Comment: @LGSon This aint the first time this has happened. People downvote most of the times without any feedback or anything, even when asked.

Answer (score -1):

I can update this if you provide me code but this how I did it in my example.

Working example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJodeZ

```
 .item {
    width: 350px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 0px 50px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper{
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
}
```